# serialize post datatables form to laravel controller for saving

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4, datatables

I have a datatables with some inputs in certain columns that are editable. I want to save the edited values in db.

This is my datatables:

[image]

The serialized datatables from values looks like this (if you `print_r($_POST)` for debugging):

[image]

**javascript** - I post the datatables form via ajax request to my laravel api controller method like this:

```
// Serialize the datatable table into post string
var poDetailUpdates = create_po_details_table.$('input').serialize();

// Call po api to save changes
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: poDetailUpdates,
    url: '/api/po/update-create-lines/',
    complete: function(response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            alert(response.responseText); // success
        } else {
            alert(response.responseText); // error
        }
    }
});
```

**php** - this is how I handle my form post in laravel:

```
public function postUpdateCreateLines() {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        foreach ($_POST as $column_name => $values) {
            foreach ($values as $line_id => $new_value) {
                DB::table('purchase_order_details')
                    ->where('id', '=', $line_id)
                    ->update(array($column_name => $new_value));
            }
        }
        DB::commit();
        Response::make('Purchase order details updated', 200);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        Response::make('Purchase order details not updated - '. $ex->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```

When the code runs, I get an empty `alert()` in javascript once the ajax request completes.

I thought the issue might be with the DB transaction related code, so I tried commenting out the following:

```
// DB::beginTransaction();
// DB::commit();
// DB::rollback();
```

But this also yields the same result (empty alert). Any idea what might be wrong? how to debug this? Something must be going wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `postUpdateCreateLines()` method is not actually returning anything; you are making a response, but you need to `return` it:

```
return Response::make('Purchase order details updated', 200);
```

---

However, there are some other improvements you could make. It is best to return a JSON response to your `$.ajax` call, and then rely on jQuery's ajax `.done` and `.fail` handlers to deal with the response appropriately (rather than using `complete`):

```
return Response::json(
    ['status' => 'success', 
     'msg'    => 'Purchase order details updated']
     , 200)
```

...and add the response `dataType` to your ajax call:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed that. the code was right, I forgot to `return` the response like you said. Good catch, thanks :)